# How to dispaly a videoview in full screen in Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-videoview

I have one video view. When i will touch that, it should display in a dialog with almost full screen view. For that i used the below code:

```
mVideoFirst.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        mVideoFirst.stopPlayback();
                        mVideoDialog.show();
                        mVideoFullScreen.setVideoPath(clip1.getAbsolutePath());
                        mMediaController3.setMediaPlayer(mVideoFullScreen);
                        mVideoFullScreen.setMediaController(mMediaController3);
                        mVideoFullScreen.requestFocus();
                        mVideoFullScreen.start();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

For the dialog i used the below java code:

```
mVideoDialog = new Dialog(this);
    mVideoDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mVideoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_video);
    mVideoDialog.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mVideoFullScreen = (VideoView) mVideoDialog.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_videoview);
```

And here is my xml vile for the dialog:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_videoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the problem is, video is playing in the dialog. But video is coming in the right side of the dialog. There is a lot of empty space in the left side of the dialog. And the controller is hiding behind the dialog. So i am not able to control the video using the video controller as i can not touch that.

Can any one help me..

Answer (score 1):

I think before `mVideoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_video);` you should call `mVideoDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`  to make the dialog full screen.

Comment: And the video controller is coming behind the alert dialog..how to overcome this issue??

Comment: Check my answer on this question to fix the video controller behind dialog. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25227176/2693789

Answer (score 0):

You need to set layout and video view height and width as match parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</VideoView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom video view control like this :

```js
public class FullScreenVideoView extends VideoView {
    public FullScreenVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FullScreenVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FullScreenVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

and use this control in your xml :

```js
   <com.yourpackagename.FullScreenVideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Dialog screen :

```js
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_dialog_xml, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        final Dialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
```