# DialogFragment issues with screen orientation and MediaController

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, mediacontroller

I have an app which plays videos in a `DialogFragment`. I have added `MediaController` to the `VideoView` however there are two issues:

`MediaController` is hidden behind the `DialogFragment`.

Change in screen orientation when the `DialogFragment` is visible results in an exception that the activity has a leaked window

For the first one, I tried using `linearLayoutParent.bringChildToFront(mediaControls)` which did not work. And I do not know how to deal with the second one.

Help me out. :)

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old question, I was also displaying a `VideoView` in a `DialogFragment` and had the same issue where the `MediaController` was hidden behind the `DialogFragment`.

For anyone that is also looking at doing the same, this is what I did.

```
//Remove the mediaController from it's parent view.
((ViewGroup) mediaController.getParent()).removeView(mediaController);
//Add the mediaController to a FrameLayout within your DialogFragment.
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlsWrapper)).addView(mediaController);
```

Just make sure your `FrameLayout` fills the width of the screen, and set the gravity to the bottom of the screen.

Also note that tapping the `VideoView` will not show and hide the `MediaController` (for some reason).

So you'll need to add a `View.onClickListener` to the `VideoView` to add and remove the `MediaController`.

Answer (score 2):

To your second point:

Try `setRetainInstance(true)` in your onCreate of the Fragment. With this the Fragment will survive while the Activity gets destroyed, like on a configuration change. If you are using the support library you will need this to really prevent the closing of your Fragment:

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
     if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
         getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
         super.onDestroyView();
 }
```

This is needed to overwrite the dismiss listener of the DialogFragment.

If you have calls on the Activity from the Fragment update the context / callback accordingly to keep track of the reference to the new created Activity. Therefor you can use onAttach() or onActivityCreated().

Comment: What about the first ?

Comment: @LittleChild I never used the media controller.